# Linux DNS (nslookup)

Tags: domain-name-system

Am a newbie to DNS, installed DNS server on my linux VM and it's successful. But i have few queries about nslookup, where i was able to resolve FQDN but not was unable to resolve hostname.

Q.) How to nslookup only with hostname.

Ex:-
Below is failing for hostname:-

```
# nslookup server01
```

And Below is successful for same hostname with FQDN:-

```
# nslookup server01.example.com
```

Below is my current DNS configuartion:-

---

forward lookup zone:-

```
$TTL 86400
@       IN SOA @  server01.example.com.  (
                                2014051001      ; serial
                                        3600    ; refresh
                                        1800    ; retry
                                        604800  ; expire
                                        86400    ; minimum
)
@                     NS      server01.example.com.
                      A       127.0.0.1
@                     A   192.168.0.50
server01              A       192.168.0.50
client01             A       192.168.0.60
```

Reverse lookup zone:

```
$TTL 1D
@       IN SOA @        server01.example.com. (
                                        0       ; serial
                                        1D      ; refresh
                                        1H      ; retry
                                        1W      ; expire
                                        3H )    ; minimum
@       NS      server01.example.com.
50      PTR     server01.
60      PTR     client01.
```

---

cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search server01.example.com
domain server01.example.com
nameserver 192.168.0.50
```

---

Below working nslookup with FDQD's:-

```
# nslookup server01.example.com
Server:         192.168.0.50
Address:        192.168.0.50#53

Name:   server01.example.com
Address: 192.168.0.50

# nslookup client01.example.com
Server:         192.168.0.50
Address:        192.168.0.50#53

Name:   client01.example.com
Address: 192.168.0.60
```

---

Below nslookup failing with hostname's:-

```
nslookup server01
Server:         192.168.0.50
Address:        192.168.0.50#53

** server can't find server01: NXDOMAIN

nslookup client01
Server:         192.168.0.50
Address:        192.168.0.50#53

** server can't find client01: NXDOMAIN
```

Answer (score 8):

This is working as expected. Short names most commonly work in two circumstances:

- The domain suffix is defined in `/etc/resolv.conf`.
- The short name is defined in `/etc/hosts`.

In the case of `nslookup` and similar DNS client utilities, `/etc/hosts` isn't relevant because those programs don't consult it. This leaves your configured search suffix as the most likely issue.

The search suffix defined in `/etc/resolv.conf` won't work because it's been configured to be the FQDN of a server:

```
search server01.example.com
```

It stands to reason that these won't work:

```
# nslookup server01
# nslookup client01
```

The above commands are trying to resolve `server01.server01.example.com` and `client01.server01.example.com`, respectively. Neither of these are valid names.

Answer (score 0):

[nslookup only for hostname](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgOCX.jpg)

Thanks for providing information.

Actually, i have configured DNS inhouse by following below URL. And were he was able to nslookup only hostname(server01) and also hostname with domain(server01.example.com), so i was wondering how did he did that and if i want to nslookup only hostname successfully, how to do that.

For reference, below is the screenshot of how did he nslookup only hostname.

Configured DNS by following below URL.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMdaIeY7ozE